# Async callbacks/promises running that protractor/webdriver is not aware of

Tags: javascript, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, protractor

It's possible a log like this?

```
07-<...>.js
...
Stacktrace: [31m[31mError: Failed expectation[31m
[31m    at [object Object].<anonymous> (...06-....js)[31m[31m[22m[39m
```

So, it basically something is failing in file -06- when I'm already processing file -07- inside a suite.

Is there an option to say to protractor / webdriver.js something like "hey don't wait for previous promises to be resolved"? I guess not, but maybe there is a known scenario where this can happen.

Sorry for the little information. I can't give much more info.

This is a similar issue, I think it's related with the previous one:

```
[32m46 tests, 11 assertions, 0 failures
[39m
[launcher] BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining
```

And I have another case where I have an error stacktrace -after- the tests, assertions and failures line. Ej:

```
     032 - "alert.msg" equals text: "invalid login"[32mâœ”[39m 033 - set detailTestLevel: 1
Finished in 3 seconds. Speed: 12.89 tests per second
Last Test Id: (ch_loginvalid_enUS_122_01)
[32m33 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures
[39m
sh: 1: beep: not found

/home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654
      var result = fn();
                   ^
Error: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index:0, but there are only 0 elements
    at /home/*******/common/ext/ElementFinder.js:618:15
    at /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)
    at notifyAll     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:442:7)
    at resolve     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:420:7)
    at fulfill     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:535:5)
    at /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)
    at [object Object].then     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:522:7)
    at Object.webdriver.promise.asap     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:767:11)
    at newFrame.onComplete     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1670:25)
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.Frame_.notify_     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1914:5)
    at [object Object]._onTimeout     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1901:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
Error
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/home/*******/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:390:21)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as getText]     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:77:19)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as getText]     /home/*******/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:698:11)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/*******/common/ext/ElementFinder.js:512:16)
    at flow.execute.then.webdriverFailure (/home/*******/node_modules/jasminewd-retry/index.js:146:18)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_     /home/*******/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_     /home/*******/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1755:8)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/*******/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:2056:12)
    at [object Object].goog.async.run.processWorkQueue [as _onTimeout]     /home/*******/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/run.js:125:21)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Is there a know scenario where this is likely to happen?

Protractor version: 1.7

node version: 0.10.25

This is the code around ElementFinder:512:

```
ElementFinder.prototype.itEqualsText = function(name, text) {
  if (_.isNully(text)) { text = name; name = this.originalName; };
  var elm = this; name = name || this.originalName;
  if (_.isNully(name)) throw new Error('needs name');
  if (_.isNully(text)) throw new Error('needs text');

  // This helps with stack traces after rit (retry it) timeouts.
  // If you attempt to build the trace within an it() block you
  // lose the whole trace because of the way Jasmine build the tests.

  rit('"' + name + '" equals text: "' + text + '"', function() {
    expect(elm.waitReady()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(elm.getText()).toEqual(text);  // line 512
  });
};
```

This is the code around ElementFinder:618:

```
// Fix current Protractor implementation so it keeps a reference to the
// original index as it was on previous Protractor versions: i.e. <= 1.2.0
ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get = function(index) {
  var self = this;
  var getWebElements = function() {
    return self.getWebElements().then(function(parentWebElements) {
      var i = index;
      if (i < 0) {
        // wrap negative indices
        i = parentWebElements.length + i;
      }
      if (i < 0 || i >= parentWebElements.length) {
        throw new Error('Index out of bound. Trying to access element at ' +  // line 618
            'index:' + index + ', but there are only ' +
            parentWebElements.length + ' elements');
      }
      return [parentWebElements[i]];
    });
  };
  getWebElements.with_index_ = index; // added
  return new ElementArrayFinder(this.ptor_, getWebElements, this.locator_).
      toElementFinder_();
};
```

I ihnerited this code, so I'm not 100% of what it does. I think it gets an array index from element.all("...").get(x).

Comment: Can you show some of the code in the test case in "06"?  From the backtrace, this looks like a culprit: `at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/*******/common/ext/ElementFinder.js:512:16)`.  You have some async code or a promise that webdriver is unaware of.  The fix is to tell webdriver about the promise/async code.  But its hard to know what exactly is going wrong without some of the test code itself.

Comment: Its hard to say, but my suspicion is the `rit` may create dangling promises during a retry?  The `rit` is from some external package?  You might try creating a small test case with a `rit` that retries and see if it keeps running after an enclosing `it`.

Comment: I think you are right and the problem is related with zombie promises. rit() is defined here: https://github.com/elgalu/jasminewd/blob/jasmine_retry/index.js The project uses that fork as a dependency. I'm trying to reproduce the issue locally, unfortunately it only seems to happen in Jenkins yet.

Comment: Fancy!  I think the Line #208 (the "promise.all") is creating a promise that Protractor doesn't know about.  Capture its result and pass it to `protractor.promise.controlFlow().await()`.  Basically a bare promise isn't automatically visible to the Protractor ControlFlow, so you need to queue them up or make sure something that is queued up waits for them.

Comment: Something like this, right? https://github.com/hhaamm/jasminewd/commit/d2cc6c922c0d02fb0d33361a6b0657086f955ebe

Comment: Yep, that is my hypothesis.  If that doesn't work, just add `console.log` lines until you figure out what's going wrong. :)

Comment: Finally, I fixed this issue syncronizing my selenium-webdriver version with the Protractor's one. But, hey, thanks for all your advices! You really saw a lot of things there with only a small portion of the code. Really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

Protractor 1.7 comes with selenium-webdriver as a dependency.

So, if you use selenium-webdriver as a dependency, and can't avoid that for X reason, make sure your selenium-webdriver version in your package.json is the same as the one in the Protractor's package.json (in this case, 2.44.0).